# chef: not_if not_working

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'd like to run ssh-copy-id iff the user doesn't already have their key on the server, so I've got a not_if directive in the execute block.  I've verified that the not_if command returns 0, but the execute block runs anyway.

```
execute "add ssh key to #{shortname}" do
  not_if cmd # proceed only if server doesn't have this key
  command "echo 'If prompted for password it is already in your clipboard and you can just paste it in and hit enter'; ssh-copy-id deploy@#{hostname}"
  cmd = "ssh -o 'BatchMode yes' deploy@#{hostname} echo 'test'"
  puts cmd
end
```

```
drostie:chef-ops (ssh_copy_id)$ ssh -o 'BatchMode yes' deploy@jenkins01.c45477.blueboxgrid.com echo 'test'
test
drostie:chef-ops (ssh_copy_id)$ echo $?
0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not manage the user ssh keys on the target node that you're trying to copy it?

Answer (score 1):

Try running it in debug.  It'll give you a lot more information about why it believes it should be executing on every run.

```
chef-client -l debug
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess your not_if command is successfully running on your host, but the inner result is an error code.

That is, ssh ran normally, was able to connect, ran your one liner, ( which had an error ), then ssh successfully exited, so the block was ran.

I would second @jtimberman's suggestion ( I hear he knows a thing or two about chef :) ) and aim to manage the ssh keys via databags, roles, or environments depending on context.